# reading of barcodes are badly interpreted in silverlight app with edge

Tags: silverlight, textbox, microsoft-edge, barcode-scanner, carriage-return

I have a problem with the Silverlight application I'm working on. Before the appearance of EDGE we did not have this problem.
We have a barcode entry interface, barcodes are sent with a reader.
the component used is a 
Since then, in certain environments, the reader's carriage return seems to be misinterpreted or poorly managed and suddenly the entry of codes is disturbed by untimely sending.

We compared the hardware, the configurations etc.. impossible to find the cause of the concern, and of course we are unable to reproduce it in debug..

heeeeeelp :)

Comment: Silverlight? Abandon ship while you can.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge doesn't support Silverlight anymore. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/faqs-edge-in-the-enterprise#does-microsoft-edge--chromium-based--support-activex-controls-or-bhos-like-silverlight-or-java). I think that's why your Silverlight application doesn't work with Edge.

If your app works well in IE 11, you can run the app in [Edge IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode). You can refer to [this guide](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2188232) to configure IE mode for Edge.